# How to rename collection of pictures after adding new pictures between, including previous descriptions

Tags: rename

For example, I have a bunch of pictures in a folder, named daddy_garden

| filename |
| --- |
| daddy_garden001.jpg |
| daddy_garden002.jpg |
| ... |
| daddy_garden057.jpg |
| daddy_garden058.jpg |
| ... |

With my program 'Where Is It' I created to most of my pictures additional DESCRIPTIONS, showing up in a separate column in my file list inside 'Where Is It'. These descripions are stored in each picture-folder as a simple textfile named "descript.ion", like

| filename & description |
| --- |
| daddy_garden001.jpg Daddy with sunflowers |
| daddy_garden002.jpg damned bee |

Now I created zoomed snipped pictures and set them between the others, like

| filename | description |
| --- | --- |
| daddy_garden001.jpg | Daddy with sunflowers |
| daddy_garden001a.jpg | zoom1 |
| daddy_garden001b.jpg | zoom2 |
| daddy_garden002.jpg | damned bee |
| ... |  |
| daddy_garden057.jpg | cleaning pool |
| daddy_garden057b.jpg | oops too slippery |
| daddy_garden058.jpg | ready |
| ... |  |

Well, it's rather easy, to rename all the files in one rush with the tool "A.F.5 Rename your files" to

| filename |
| --- |
| Xdaddy_garden001.jpg |
| Xdaddy_garden002.jpg |
| Xdaddy_garden003.jpg |
| Xdaddy_garden004.jpg |
| ... |
| Xdaddy_garden058.jpg |
| Xdaddy_garden059.jpg |
| Xdaddy_garden060.jpg |
| ... |

and back to

| finaly filename |
| --- |
| daddy_garden001.jpg |
| daddy_garden002.jpg |
| daddy_garden003.jpg |
| daddy_garden004.jpg |
| ... |
| daddy_garden058.jpg |
| daddy_garden059.jpg |
| daddy_garden060.jpg |
| ... |

but all the descriptions now would have to be renamed manually in the file "descript.ion", or they will show up with the wrong (former) filename.

Ten or fifteen years before I used ACDsee to do that, but it no longer works now with Win10, new versions are rather complicated and I don't know, if it can do that kind of renaming and transferring the descriptons to the new filename too.

Can anybody help about that? Is there another way to do this also on much larger folders containing a couple hundred images?

Comment: Have you considered Power Renamer contained within [Power Tools](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys)?

Comment: So you want to rename all the files but don't touch the part between brakets "[ ]" is that it?

Comment: Is it something like this: https://i.imgur.com/WeEqFPl.gif
Or don't you want the files that have [ ] on them to be touched at all?

Comment: Thank you (Ramhound & Ricardo Bohner) very much for your fast answers and please excuse me for my bad English and the very long delay. I just now tried to learn about the table formatting, and maybe its now a bit more clear, what I have meant about the descriptions (comments) I added to most of my pictures.

Comment: I will try out the Power Tools, Ramhound suggested. Maybe it can take with it the descriptions not only during moving, copying bunches of files and folders (as "Where Is It" does) but even hold the descriptions renaming bunch of files in a single folder.

I soon will tell you about my results.